# Contiki sensor data upload to ubidots.com

Tags: contiki

I have two z1 motes and wants to upload temperature readings to cloud using website www.ubidots.com

I followed the steps mentioned in the link :

https://www.hackster.io/4348/zolertia-ipv6-6lowpan-ubidots

Border Router logs:

```
tun       Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet6 addr: 2001:5c0:1400:a::495/128 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1280  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Rime started with address 193.12.0.0.0.0.19.165
MAC c1:0c:00:00:00:00:13:a5 Contiki-2.6-900-ga6227e1 started. Node id is set to 5029.
CSMA ContikiMAC, channel check rate 8 Hz, radio channel 26
Tentative link-local IPv6 address fe80:0000:0000:0000:c30c:0000:0000:13a5
Starting 'Border router process' 'Web server'
*** Address:aaaa::1 => aaaa:0000:0000:0000
Got configuration message of type P
Setting prefix aaaa::
Server IPv6 addresses:
 aaaa::c30c:0:0:13a5
 fe80::c30c:0:0:13a5
```

Added Ubidots variable Ids in project-conf.h

running Ubidots-demo.c on another z1 mote
I get the logs :

```
Ubidots client: STATE_RESOLVING (3)
Ubidots client: STATE_RESOLVING (3)
Ubidots client: STATE_RESOLVING (3)
Ubidots client: STATE_RESOLVING (3)
Ubidots client: STATE_RESOLVING (4)
Ubidots client: STATE_RESOLVING (4)
```

If anybody also faced same errors
Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score -2):

You need here to modify your Ubuntu machine or raspberry pi if using,

Following three files need to be modify :

1. etc/radvd.conf
2. etc/network/interfaces
3. etc/sysctl.conf

   like this :
     http://koo.fi/blog/2013/03/20/linux-ipv6-router-radvd-dhcpv6/

bye